# How can i sum every nth number from list recursively?

Tags: python

I want to add every nth number from list recursively, but NOT the first number, so lets say I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and I want to add every **2nd** number, so that would mean I need to add `2 + 4 + 6` but if I want to add every **3rd** number, then it should add `3 + 6`.

So right now I have this much, I want to add every 2nd number so that means I want to add `2`, `4` and `6`, but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work, what should I do differently?

```
def getsum(numbers):
    if len(piece)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return getsum(numbers[2:]) + numbers[0]  
print getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: You say "NOT the first number", then include `numbers[0]`.

Comment: This is not a good case for recursion.  Just use builtin `sum` and slicing.

Comment: @wim: It is a fine case for *learning* about recursion.

Comment: @wim i already did one iteratively, but now im trying to do it recursively because i read that everything you can do iteratively, you can also do recursively

Comment: `return getsum(numbers[2:]) + numbers[1] `

Comment: @ScottHunter well yes, true, but i cant figure out how can i then add the numbers after it does the recursion

Comment: @dcg if i try with 3, it doesnt give me a correct answer

Comment: @SecretSanta you have to change the indexes depending on the value. @CoryKramer gave the general case (if `n = 2`: `numbers[n - 1] = numbers[1]` and `getsum(numbers[n:]) = getsum(numbers[2:])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick out the `n`th number, then recursively slice off everything after that when you call the function again

```
def get_sum(numbers, n):
    if len(numbers) < n:
        return 0
    return numbers[n-1] + get_sum(numbers[n:], n)
```

For example with n = 2 and n = 3 respectively

```
>>> get_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)    # 2 + 4 + 6
12
>>> get_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)    # 3 + 6
9
```